# Meaning of c(...) in RStudio's data browser

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, rstudio

As you know, when working in `RStudio` and calling `View()` in **R** module, sourcing this module results in opening RStudio's internal data browser window. While most simple data is understandable, I'm confused by seeing data like this: `c(NA, NA, NA, 125125, NA)`. What does it represent? This looks like standard **R** notation for *vectors*. However, I expect an **embedded** *data frame* in that spot. Would appreciate clarification!

Comment: String probably View("c(NA, NA, NA, 125125, NA)")

Comment: @Aashu: Thank you for the comment. You're right that it's string from the data browser's perspective. However, I was curious about the **reason** for such _encoding_. I guess, it's a question for Jeroen Ooms, as that data has been produced by his `jsonlite` library. Not sure if he will read this, so I will try to contact him via e-mail.

Comment: make your question reproducible. The object is coerced into a data frame, so like aashu said, that object was probably a string, but we cannot know for sure since this is not reproducible.

Comment: @rawr: Thank you! It's not that easy to make this question reproducible, since the processing involves quite a bit of code. However, the more I think about it, the more I feel that the answer lies in how the package I'm using represents data. I contacted the package's author and, depending on his answer, I will decide on next steps. Will update this thread accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c(...)` does indeed mean "vector" in RStudio's data browser.. Here's a minimal reproducible example.

```
set.seed(1)
df1   <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:10])
# each element of df1$x is char
df1$x <- sapply(1:10,function(i)do.call(paste,as.list(letters[sample(1:10,5)])))
# each element of df2$x is a vector of char
df2   <- aggregate(x~id,df1,function(x)strsplit(as.character(x)," "))
View(df2)
```

In the above, each element of `df1$x` is a character string with 5 random, space-separated characters. The "aggregate" function in this example runs `strsplit(...)` on each value of `df1$x` to return a vector of characters, which are stored in the elements of `df2$x`. So when you `View(df2)` in RStudio, it reflects the fact that each element of `df2$x` is a vector.

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment)

This creates a dataframe (`df1`) where each element of `df1$z` is a dataframe.

```
df1   <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:3])
df    <- data.frame(id=rep(letters[1:3],each=10),x=rnorm(30), y=rnorm(30))
df1$z <- split(df,df$id)
View(df1)
```

Note that RStudio displays `df1$z` as a list of vectors, which is, in fact, the underlying structure of a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Great example, if a little too advanced (for my gentle level of R comprehension :-)! Up-voting and accepting as the answer for my question! Would you mind modifying your example (separately) to View() a data frame, containing data frames as embedded elements?

Comment: But can you use a different letter than c for a vector?

Comment: @Siyah: Probably, not, unless you define another single-letter function that calls `c()`. Based on R documentation, 'c' in `c()` refers to **combining** values into a _vector_ or _list_, so, considering _multiple options_, the existing naming makes sense.