# c() function in R means

Tags: r, function

What does the 'c' in the ***`c()`*** function of R really stand for?

My efforts to answer this question gave conflicting results (*Big names in the R community disagree*):

- Some (*`Crawley - 2007; Zuur et al. - 2009; Matloff - 2011; and Cotton - 2013`*) say it means "**concatenate**."
- Others (*`Lander - 2014; Kabacoff - 2015; and Wickham - 2015`*) say it means "**combine**."

We can write code just fine without knowing what the `c` means, but it's a mystery why an answer isn't agreed upon by very prominent figures in the R community.

Comment: To find the canonical answer you'd probably have the best luck consulting the source code for R base (I imagine `c()` is defined in the C source code) and hoping for a comment. There most likely isn't unanimous agreement in the community  because no one cares very much - combine and concatenate are close enough in meaning to convey the point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of c(...) in RStudio's data browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172064/meaning-of-c-in-rstudios-data-browser)

Comment: It means concatenate, which in common language means to link or chain things together, which is what you do when you use c(). It is easier to say combine, but it is a less articulate explanation of what you are doing, there are many ways of combining, but linking via a chain implies an order that is respected by concatenation. It is more precise whether it is 100% by design or not.

Comment: In case anyone is interested - there are no illuminating comments. R Core Team refers to the function only as `c()` :) https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/bind.c

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Bethany! I suspect your reply gives the real meaning, but felt apprehensive about not agreeing with Lander, Kabacoff & Wickham, who are all so prominent.

Comment: AP - Thank you for the helpful edits!

Comment: you are welcome, mr.bob!

Answer (score 4):

If you ask the R help it says combine:

```
?c
```

> Combine Values into a Vector or List
>
> Description
>
> This is a generic function which combines its arguments.
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Harald! I should have mentioned in my question that I checked R help too, and saw that it said "combine." I wasn't sure if that settled the matter, since some big names weighed in for "concatenate."